# How to debug Flink itself using Intellij IDEA

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, apache-flink

I want to study stream principles through the flink source code, I need to debug it and see how it works
I've compiled the Flink source code and imported the project to Intellij IEDA, but I cannot run it as a standalone cluster. I am working on Windows 10 with JDK 11 and maven 3.6.3
I set the main class as

```
org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.StandaloneSessionClusterEntrypoint
```

and run it from IDEA, but I got some warnings and an excetion

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil (file:/C:/Users/%e5%88%98%e8%bf%9c%e5%8d%9a/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-auth/2.8.5/hadoop-auth-2.8.5.jar) to method sun.security.krb5.Config.getInstance()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:221)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.shutDownAsync(ClusterEntrypoint.java:586)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.startCluster(ClusterEntrypoint.java:242)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint.runClusterEntrypoint(ClusterEntrypoint.java:729)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.StandaloneSessionClusterEntrypoint.main(StandaloneSessionClusterEntrypoint.java:59)
```

How can I start JobManager and debug it?

I try to start a JobManager and then a TaskManager through Flink sourc code using IDEA. And I wish I could debug them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved by configing VM opitons and Program arguments.
With Windows10 the VM options are:

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:{source_code_path}\flink-1.16.0\flink-dist\target\flink-1.16.0-bin\flink-1.16.0\conf\my-log4j-console.properties 
-classpath {source_code_path}\flink-1.16.0\flink-dist\target\flink-1.16.0-bin\flink-1.16.0\lib\flink-cep-1.16.0.jar;{source_code_path}\flink-1.16.0\flink-dist\target\flink-1.16.0-bin\flink-1.16.0\lib\flink-connector-files-1.16.0.jar;{source_code_path}\flink-1.16.0\flink-dist\target\flink-1.16.0-bin\flink-1.16.0\lib\flink-csv-1.16.0.jar;{source_code_path}\flink-1.16.0\flink-dist\target\flink-1.16.0-bin\flink-1.16.0\lib\flink-dist-1.16.0.jar;{source_code_path}\flink-1.16.0\flink-dist\target\flink-1.16.0-bin\flink-1.16.0\lib\flink-json-1.16.0.jar;{source_code_path}\flink-1.16.0\flink-dist\target\flink-1.16.0-bin\flink-1.16.0\lib\flink-scala_2.12-1.16.0.jar;{source_code_path}\flink-1.16.0\flink-dist\target\flink-1.16.0-bin\flink-1.16.0\lib\flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.5.9.jar;{source_code_path}\flink-1.16.0\flink-dist\target\flink-1.16.0-bin\flink-1.16.0\lib\flink-table-api-java-uber-1.16.0.jar;{source_code_path}\flink-1.16.0\flink-dist\target\flink-1.16.0-bin\flink-1.16.0\lib\flink-table-planner-loader-1.16.0.jar;{source_code_path}\flink-1.16.0\flink-dist\target\flink-1.16.0-bin\flink-1.16.0\lib\flink-table-runtime-1.16.0.jar;{source_code_path}\flink-1.16.0\flink-dist\target\flink-1.16.0-bin\flink-1.16.0\lib\log4j-core-2.17.1.jar;{source_code_path}\flink-1.16.0\flink-dist\target\flink-1.16.0-bin\flink-1.16.0\lib\log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.1.jar;{source_code_path}\flink-1.16.0\flink-dist\target\flink-1.16.0-bin\flink-1.16.0\lib\log4j-1.2-api-2.17.1.jar;{source_code_path}\flink-1.16.0\flink-dist\target\flink-1.16.0-bin\flink-1.16.0\lib\log4j-api-2.17.1.jar;
```

And the Program arguments is

```
-c flink-dist\target\flink-1.16.0-bin\flink-1.16.0\conf
```

The target path is a little bit different from those on Liunx

Answer (score 0):

Just write a simple workflow (or use one of the many examples provided on the Flink website), and execute it using a LocalStreamEnvironment. That will automatically start a JobManager & TaskManager, as part of the Flink MiniCluster.

Comment: I know this can start a MiniCluster and let me debug the workflow but it won't help me to debug Flink itself, such as how the JobManager communicate with TaskManager; how Flink create a DAG and manage resources etc.

Comment: The Flink MiniCluster is more similar to a cluster running in separate JVMs than you seem to expect. The client will still create the DAG and submit it to the job manager, which will communicate with the task manager, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The NPE you've mentioned is thrown on shutdown hook and is hiding the original exception. The original exception is `NoClassDefFoundError` for log4j classes. That's because these dependencies have the `provided` scope. See https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/flinkdev/ide_setup/#examples-fail-with-a-noclassdeffounderror-for-flink-classes. In order to fix it you need to change log4j dependencies' scope in flink-parent pom.xml:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <!-- API bridge between log4j 1 and 2 -->
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

**To run jobmanager:**

main class:

```
org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.StandaloneSessionClusterEntrypoint
```

arguments:

```
-c flink-dist\target\flink-{version}-bin\flink-{version}\conf
```

VM options (optional, enables logs):

```
-Dlog4j.configurationFile={source_code_path}/flink-dist/target/flink-{version}-bin/flink-{version}/conf/log4j-console.properties
```

**To run taskmanager:**

main class:

```
org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner
```

arguments:

```
-c flink-dist\target\flink-{version}-bin\flink-{version}\conf
```

VM options:

```
-Dlog4j.configurationFile={source_code_path}/flink-dist/target/flink-{version}-bin/flink-{version}/conf/log4j-console.properties
-Dtaskmanager.memory.network.min=134217730b
-Dtaskmanager.cpu.cores=10.0
-Dtaskmanager.memory.task.off-heap.size=0b
-Dtaskmanager.memory.jvm-metaspace.size=268435456b
-Dtaskmanager.memory.jvm-overhead.min=201326592b
-Dtaskmanager.memory.framework.off-heap.size=134217728b
-Dtaskmanager.memory.network.max=134217730b
-Dtaskmanager.memory.framework.heap.size=134217728b
-Dtaskmanager.memory.managed.size=536870920b
-Dtaskmanager.memory.task.heap.size=402653174b
-Dtaskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots=10
-Dtaskmanager.memory.jvm-overhead.max=201326592b
```

If this doesn't work for some reason, see `flink-dist/src/main/flink-bin/bin/jobmanager.sh` and `flink-dist/src/main/flink-bin/bin/taskmanager.sh` to find the actual params that are passed on a startup.